# Figuring out when $x^3=\sin(x)$

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

So, I have to find all the equilibrium solutions of each of the following systems of equations and determine, if possible, whether they are stable or unstable.

\begin{align*}
  x' &= \,y + \cos y - 1 \\ 
  y' &=  - \sin x + x^3
\end{align*}

And I know already that $y=0$ and $x=0$ is a solution, but I don't know what to do when $(-\sin(x)-x^3)=0$. I thought maybe the Taylor series of $\sin(x)$ might help, but I got nowhere.
Any insight might be great.

Comment: Plot those functions in desmos, and note the intersection point, but surely I can tell that  x should contain inside $-1\lt x\lt 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $|\sin x|\le 1$ you get directly $|x|^3\le1\implies |x|\le 1$. Then the sine series due to its alternating nature provides the bounds for $\sqrt6>x>0$ (and symmetrically also for $x<0$)
$$
x-\frac16x^3\le\sin x\le x
\\~\\
x^3-x\le x^3-\sin x\le \frac76x^3-x
$$
This implies a sign change from negative to positive on the interval $[\sqrt{\frac67},1]$, thus a root there. There will be no symbolic formula for the solution $0.9286263..$ of the transcendental equation $0=x^3-\sin x$ in this interval.